# Are example.com and blog.example.com treated as one if they have the same content?

Tags: seo, search-engines, duplicate-content

I have a site, say **example.com** and it's blog is **blog.example.com**. Please note trusty.com and blog.trusty.com are both hosted with different hosting companies and **have different IP Addresses**.

If I have the **same content in both**  example.com and blog.example.com **will search engines flag this as duplicate content**, or will they assume it is the part of the same domain?

If you are wondering why I have the same content on both locations, it is because it appears in different "packaging" in both places.

Comment: See also: [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

Answer (score 3):

It will be duplicate content regardless of how the search engines view it (which they do view it as one site [since there is no difference between subdirectories and subfolders](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/subdomains-and-subdirectories/)). So you will have duplicate content issues. To remedy this you need to choose which one is the main site and use [canconical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) to cite it as the main source of that content.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate Content is identified on-line without any difference between IP addresses, hosting packages and URL`s.
Will take a while for Google to discover that the content is similar at both sites and will punish you, or simply suppress results for one of the sites.
The question is, with the same content whether organic Seo is the solution you need.
PPC campaign will be perhaps a better solution for you?